# Converting to join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I've got a query that's rather inefficient, and I think that I can use SQL JOIN to cut it down.

Here are the two queries:

```
$data = $db->query("SELECT * from tbl_forums_threads WHERE tid = '$id'");
$threaddata = $data->fetch_assoc();
$dataset = $db->query("SELECT * from tbl_forums_posts WHERE tid = '$id'");
$thread = $dataset->fetch_assoc();
```

Obviously, they have 1 thing in common: the use of $id.

Could I use SQL JOIN, or even LEFT JOIN?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for effective use of `SELECT *` in a web application

Comment: more than that yuo should say he isn't using PDO for params.

Comment: I couldn't tell if it was sarcastic, but it actually uses all of the information given in all columns.

Comment: I suspect you could use a `UNION ALL` if the tables are similar anyway. (Not faster, but just one query.) - The problem seems you are implementing a bulletin board, not a true forum, hencewhy the scattered table struct?

Comment: PHP can be abstracted away here. This is a MySQL question.

Comment: Hi Mario, yep - I'm sort of building it in to an intranet, based on the person previous to me's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 SQL query with a JOIN isn't necessarily faster than a 2 simple query like that.

Stay with this imo.

Comment: One query with a join and two queries (as is above) are completely different things, so I don't think it's fair to make *any* sort of comparison.

Comment: True enough, but providing a comparison that doesn't mean anything is less valuable than telling them that such a comparison *wouldn't* mean anything, IMO ;)

Answer (score 2):

You'd get far better improvements by creating indices on the `tid` column in each table than you would by changing the queries.

Simple `select`s on a single table with a basic where clause should not be slow; if they are, it's probably because they're not using an index. In this case, you're only filtering on one field, so that's the only possibility for needing an index.

Comment: +1. Assuming the index isn't already there, this is likely the best solution to the performance issue. FWIW, with MySQL it's also probably worth knowing which storage engine is in use.

Comment: And I would also `LIMIT` the amount of results to avoid wasting precious ram.

Comment: @hexa: That is assuming that he doesn't want/need the entire data set.

Comment: @Adam Of course. I assumed it's a forum and usually you don't want all the posts of a thread at once :P

Comment: At the moment, it's not slow, however, as time progresses, and with the number of records to search for filling, it could become a bit slow.

Comment: @Shamil - "premature optimization is the root of all evil"; if it's not slow now, what reason do you have to believe it will become slow, and more specifically, that a different way *won't* become just as slow?

Comment: @hexa, yep, that's correct :) I'll be introducing pagination, and thus adding LIMIT soon.